# insertNewObjectForEntityForName at first position in the table not last

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

How to insert the record with coredata at first position in table? currently if i add `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` it adds record to last.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as i know this is not possible. However one thing you could do is manipulate how the objects are retrieved from the DB. For example, for such requirements it is often useful to have an NSDate property in your model class. While inserting objects into the DB, pass [NSDate date] for this property. And while pulling out objects from the DB, write a sorting algorithm which returns the records sorted by the Date of insertion

In your model class' header file 
Header.h

```
//Declare this property
NSDate *dateOfInsertion


//This method returns objects sorted by DateOf Insertion
    - (NSArray*)arraySortedByDateOfInsertion {
        NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dateOfInsertion" ascending:NO];
        return [self sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];

    }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You cannot decide where to add element in the table. But you use array for this . You can add the element at the top of the array so it will appeared as a first row in the table :

```
- (void)insertObject:(id)anObject atIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```